# Setting a PFUser.CurrentUser() pointer field

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am currently working on a project using Parse, and I am having a hard time changing a value. So for every user, there is a field called "privateData", which also has fields. To access it, I have no problem doing this:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!["privateData"]!["locations"]!
```

However, when I try to change "locations, I always get errors. Field name invalid, cannot subscript a value of type ... or trying to change immutable value.

I tried:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!["privateData"]!["locations"]! = bla bla bla
```

I get "Trying to change immutable value"

and when I user .valueForKey:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!["privateData"]!.valueForKey("locations",blabla)
```

I get error 105, bad field name.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Charles

Comment: so `privateData` is some other `PFObject`?  Have you fetched that object?  Try not to do everything in one line.  Get the `PFObject` reference from your `PFUser` and use the debugger to make sure it has been fetched and actually contains data.  Also it sounds like your locations data is possibly an NSArray, in which case you will need to make a mutable copy, modify it and then put it back

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for helping me out. Yes, privateData is another PFObject. User is pointing to it and I am trying to access its field "location". And it is indeed an Array, an array of dictionary.

Comment: So, if you haven't specified `includeKey` for privateData when you fetched the user, you will need to access `privateData` as a PFObject and fetch it.  I recommend you set a breakpoint and have a look at the data in the debugger.

Comment: Hey Paul, I did include key when the user is logging in.